# Rounded corner when table overflows div?

Tags: html, css, html-table, overflow

I have a structure similar to the code below. When the table is too tall for the content container it hides the overflow content. My problem is the bottom corners of the visible table are square, despite the rounded lower corners of it's container div. Is there a way to round off the bottom without putting a gap between the bottom of the table and the bottom of its container div?

Here's a demo to recreate the problem 
 http://www.jsbin.com/ohejor/1/edit

```
<div class='container'>
<table>
    ....table populated by php pulling from mysql table
</table>
</div>
```

and the CSS

```
table{ overflow:auto;}
.container{ position:relative; height:75%;  border-radius:0px 0px 5px 5px;}
```

Comment: What about setting a max-height for the container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you should be setting overflow-y on the container and not the table:

```
table{}
.container{ position:relative; height:75%; border-radius:0px 0px 5px 5px; overflow-y: auto}
```

Comment: thank you! overflow-y is just what I was looking for, although I used :hidden instead of :auto in order to hide the scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

The corners of the `table` are square because while you've declared `border-radius` for the `div.container`, you haven't done so for the `table`.

To round the `table` corners:

```
table { border: solid red 1px; border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px; }
```

To prevent spacing between `div.container` and `table`:

```
.container { padding: 0px;}
```

Comment: the problem is not getting the table to have a border. the problem is that the bottom of the table isn't shown, the "bottom" is just the lowest <tr> that isn't being hidden by overflow:auto, so it's a square corner. What i'm trying to achieve is using the outer container as a sort of mask to cut off the bottom corner.

Comment: @ejfrancis - Ah.  Can you please provide an example which demonstrates the problem? I really can't guess at what your content is...

Comment: here is a demo, note that the container has a rounded corner before clicking the button, but after the <tr> overlaps it with a square corner http://jsbin.com/ohejor/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

`border-collapse: collapse` added to table selector should help.